# Google Cloud Storage : create bucket with ACL

Tags: java, acl, google-cloud-storage

I can create bucket but I do not find how to change bucket's acl when I create it.
I want everyone can read the objects but not write.

To create bucket :

```
Storage storage = new Storage(......);
storage.buckets().insert(projectName, new Bucket().setName(bucketName)).execute();
```

I saw that I can use :

```
new Bucket().setAcl(List<BucketAccessControl>)
```

How to use .setAcl methode ?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is set the [default object ACL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#defaultobjects) for the bucket. This will apply an ACL to all new objects uploaded to the bucket.

To do that, you can use the [setPredefinedDefaultObjectAcl](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/storage/Storage.Buckets.Insert.html#setPredefinedDefaultObjectAcl(java.lang.String)) method of the [Storage.Buckets.Insert](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/storage/Storage.Buckets.Insert.html) operation returned from your `storage.buckets().insert` call.

Take a look at the [Applying a predefined ACL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#predefined-acl) section of the documentation for the list of predefined ACLs. In this case, you probably want to use `publicRead`.